# How to git pull with custom commit message?

Tags: git, merge

I'm in a big problem. I was in a new working environment and working with a team. They are pushing straight to the `master` branch for new features while I used to work in a separate branch myself, on my private repositories. (I thought that this development method was best practice, never actually worked with a team).

I once developed a feature and pulled the `master` branch to my `feature-x` then push it to my my branch but it triggers the the deployment and replaced the production app with one from my latest `git pull` commit.

I reported it to my seniors and they say it's fine because it's my first day joining them. But they say I should be careful when merging stuffs.

After I check the CI script, it turns out that the deployment script will be executed if there is a word `Merge` and `--deploy` in commit message on ANY branch. So I need to change my merge commit message produced by `git pull` to another message.. Is it possible?

And yes, I know that `git pull` is a shorthand for `git fetch` and `git merge`I read from another similar question on SO but I just can't grasp that fast by reading the docs because I'm not a native English speaker. The deadline is near* and I'm panicked.

I'm afraid if I do `git fetch` and `git merge` manually, I'll messed up merging my unfinished branch to the `master` branch instead of merging `master` to my branch.

Please help! What is the safest command to fetch and merge with custom message?

*I have committed all my work and just need to pull from `master` before pushing to my branch and make a pull request.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---edit? You may also want to consider _not_ working in a different way to the rest of the team, as that may limit their ability to help you, or using _rebasing_ rather than merging to keep your branch up-to-date with master.

Comment: Yes I read that before I posted my question, but I don't have enough time to grasp it in a very short time. As for the consideration, I'll take it seriously and try to follow the way they work on the project. I'll take this as a lesson. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I need to change my merge commit message produced by git pull to another message.. Is it possible?

Yes. After the pull, if a merge commit was created, say

```
git commit --amend
```

You will be asked for a replacement commit message.

However, you should have done this together with the pull, by saying

```
git pull --edit
```

> And yes, I know that git pull is a shorthand for git fetch and git mergeI read from another similar question on SO but I just can't grasp that

Grasp it. You never need to say `pull`; it is confusing and dangerous. To merge master into the branch you are on, say

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Again, to avoid having to rewrite the commit message later, say

```
git fetch
git merge --edit origin/master
```

You asked: "What is the safest command to fetch and merge with custom message?" That.

(It is also possible to configure your Git so that a merge commit *always* offers you the chance to edit its message. I prefer it that way. Recent Git versions are set up this way by default; you might be using a somewhat outdated Git, else the problem would never have arisen.)

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting your answer cuz I need more help.. I ran your command but it still gave me `Merge remote-tracking branch ...` message in my local commit, is that normal?

Comment: i was doing it like `git fetch && git merge --edit origin/master` and then I typed `esc` and `:wq` to exit the prompt.. Am I doing it wrong? Please let me know

Comment: That is the commit message you now would edit with `git commit --amend`.

Comment: Also I think you might be using a really old version of Git. I recommend updating.

Comment: Learning to edit a commit message using vim or whatever is a separate topic.

Comment: Yes I'll keep that in mind. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to do git pull as usual, then run :

```
git commit --amend -m"New commit message"
```

This will rewrite the last commit message that was commited.

Be aware that you should not use this if you already pushed that particular commit, because this will then need you to do git push --force which is usually bad practice.

Note that you can create a new branch for your current changes before doing the merge with master.